# Docker container - INTERNAL only TCP ports to communicate between 2 components inside the same container

Tags: docker, containers

I am trying to find if there are any gotchas in exposing a port (tcp) inside a container and then another process consuming (reading/writing) to the same port INSIDE the SAME container. Should i need to compose/expose/publish this port ? 
So basically, is there anything specific to be done/aware to expose a port in a container for internal (to the same container) purposes?

Answer (score 0):

In such a case there is nothing specific to be done. You can ignore any docker thing (expose or publish port).

Just have the second process in that container connect to `localhost:<port of opened by the first process>`

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining the lifecycle of the two processes correctly is tricky.  If one process dies, you want *something* to notice and either kill the other process or restart the one, and you probably want to know this is happening.  `docker logs` probably won't automatically combine the two processes' outputs (and depending on how you launch them may not capture either).  If one process needs more compute power than the other, you can't scale one without scaling the other; if you update the software in one process you can't restart it without restarting the other.

In short: this is not typically encouraged as a best practice; running the processes in two separate containers is generally preferred.

If you do do this, *in this circumstance only*, the two processes in the same container will see each other as `localhost`, and you can pass that as the environment-variable setting for one process to see the other.  You don't specifically need to "expose" or "publish" the port.  A typical `docker-compose.yml` file might look like

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    ports: ['8080:8080']
    env:
      - BACKEND_URL: 'http://localhost:12345'
```

but a better `docker-compose.yml` file could look like

```
version: 3
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    ports: ['8080:8080']
    env:
      - BACKEND_URL: 'http://backend:12345'
    command: 'myapp -bind 0.0.0.0:8080'
  backend:
    build: .
    command: 'backend -bind 0.0.0.0:12345'
```